# Where memory is corrupted?

Tags: c

I can't get where memory is corrupted, i send pointer to FooFile_Factory, it allocates memory on Heap and initialize it. But when controls returns to the void that called FooFile_Factory, allocated memory is 
corrupted / random values. Can't understand why?

```
typedef struct _FOO_FILE{
    PFLT_CONTEXT StreamContext;
    ...
} FOO_FILE, *PFOO_FILE;



NTSTATUS
FooFile_Factory(
_Out_ PFOO_FILE pFile
)
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    pFile = ExAllocatePoolWithTag( //Allocation on heap
        NonPagedPool,
        sizeof(FOO_FILE),
        FOO_FILES_TAG);

    if (!pFile) {
        return INSTALL_MORE_MEMORY;
    }

    RtlZeroMemory(pFile, sizeof(FOO_FILE));

    //Some Initializatoin

    //Here pFile fields values are correct, PFLT_CONTEXT is null
    return status;
}

NTSTATUS
VoidThatCall()
{
NTSTATUS status;

PFOO_FILE pFile = NULL;
status = FooFile_Factory(pFile);
//--> Here PFOO_FILE fields values became corrupted (PFLT_CONTEXT give memory access error)

...
}
```

Comment: By "memory corrupted" do you mean that `pFile` is still `NULL`?

Comment: What is the actual error or un/expected difference?

Comment: pFile is null after FooFile_Factory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can find an analogy:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f(int n) { n = 42; }
int main(void) { int n = 3; f(n); printf("%d\n", n); return 0; }
```

Because of function call by value, `3` will be printed.

In your example, the same happens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f(int *p) { p = ...; }
int main(void) { int *p = NULL; f(p); printf("%p\n", (void *)p); return 0; }
```

The value of `p` in the calling function won't be changed. One way to solve it is to use a pointer to pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f(int **p) { *p = ...; }
int main(void) { int *p = NULL; f(&p); printf("%p\n", (void *)p); return 0; }
```